# Scheduled Annotation in Spring (call after a certain time for each value)

Tags: java, spring

I am working at the moment with @Scheduled Annotation in Spring. What i want to do is, to remove a value from a list after 10 minutes, so the value can only least 10 minutes after creation. Is there a way to implement this with @Scheduled Annotation?

**Example:**

```
public int values(){
 for(int i = 0; i < 10;++i){
 Random ran = new Random();
 int x = ran.nextInt(6) + 5;
 list.add(x);
 }
}
```

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 600000)
public void removeValue(){
 list.remove(list.size()-1);
}
```

In this example the value gets deleted after 10 minutes. Then i have to wait 10 minutes to delete the next value, but what if the last values are created straight after the deleted value. In summary, i want to call removeValue() after a value in list is 10 minutes old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be a very good example with a simple `List` object element, but you can do what you want to do using your own model or the `Map` interface.

First of all, you can simply add your elements to a `Map` interface and delete them in a minimum of 10 minutes by keeping an `expired time` for each element. The example in the link can be a reference for the map interface. [How to Remove expired elements from HashMap and Add more elements at the Same Time – Java Timer, TimerTask and futures() – Complete Example](https://crunchify.com/clean-expired-element-from-map-while-adding-elements-at-the-same-time-java-timer-timertask-and-futures-complete-examples/)

If you have a database entity; you can call these expired elements and delete them from the database. As an example, I had a code block like this.

**To sum up, I take elements whose creation date is older than 10 minutes. All that remains is to delete this.**

```
Date retentionDate = org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.addMinutes(new Date(), -10);
List<?> items = service.findAllByCreationDateBefore(retentionDate);
```

**Remember to set the `fixedRate` value accordingly for how long you want Elaman to stay for more than 10 minutes.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was, if there is a way to do this with Scheduled Annotation in Spring

Comment: It is not possible to do it with @ Scheduled annotation, it offers you to work only with a certain time schedule. scenarios and logics should be under your control. You benefit from @ Scheduled annotation instead of a timer as in the example. you will actually do it with @ Scheduled annotation.

Comment: Okay thanks, i thought there was a mechanism for that